# Creating an AsymmetricCipherKeyPair with just the Public key

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle

I'm having a bit of an issue. I'm trying to write a client-server application (more a POC really), with the client requesting the public key from the server, the server then generates this key `AsymmetricCipherKeyPair` with the following

```
    private static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair GenerateKeyPair() {
      RsaKeyPairGenerator g = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
      g.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 1024));
      var pair = g.GenerateKeyPair();
      return pair;
}
```

This generates correctly and can encrypt and encrypt correctly(on the server side, but that defeats the purpose)

So I then send a serialized public key to the client

```
    private static byte[] SerialisePublic(AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keypair) {
    SubjectPublicKeyInfo publicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(keypair.Public);
    byte[] serializedPublicBytes = publicKeyInfo.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded();
    return serializedPublicBytes;
}
    private static void SendBytes(TcpClient client, byte[] send) {
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    stream.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
    stream.Flush();
}
```

However now, when I try to initialise the `keypair` on the otherside, I need a private key (which also defeats the purpose)

I tried the following

```
 static string EncryptString(string key, string message) {
        string res = "";
        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(128)) {
            try {
                rsa.FromXmlString(string.Format("<RSAKeyValue>{0}</RSAKeyValue>", key));
                byte[] b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                var encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(b, true);
                var base64Encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
                res = base64Encrypted;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
            }
            finally {
                rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
```

(In the absence of a keypair, I thought I could hack it)

however as this does not contain nearly half the information required for encryption, it fails, hard.

I'd like to keep to using Bouncy Castle if possible, however I am open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

---

> UPDATE

Both client and server are being written in C#

---

> Update 2 (thanks Andrew)

This will initialise the `RsaEngine` with the public key provide by the server(or at least is should) (This didn't work, don't use it)

```
    static byte[] EncryptBytes(byte[] key, byte[] message) {
        byte[] res = null;
        AsymmetricKeyParameter ic = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(key);
        RsaEngine e = new RsaEngine();
        e.Init(true, ic);
        res = e.ProcessBlock(message, 0, message.Length);
        return res;
    }
```

---

> Update 3

So that didn't work, the `PublicKeyFactory` doesn't seem to like the returned key
throwing: `Unknown object in GetInstance: Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerApplicationSpecific`

I think it could be an issue in the Serialisation on server side and then the deserialisation on the client side.

So maybe a `CryptoStream` for the transmission of a public key and additional authentication (passphrase, secret knock or a joke) when a client connects to a server.

stay tuned

---

Comment: I don't understand, do you want the client and the server to each have both the public and private keys? Why?

Comment: Hi Andrew, no I don't. 

My intention is to pass the public key to the client, then the client uses this to encrypt the data and sends it back to the server.
The server then decrypts this data and processes it.

This is my first attempt at using encryption and the Bouncy Castle Libraries.

To initialise an AsymmetricCipherKeyPair, it requires two arguments (Public and Private keys) both of which are read-only (so that took another quick hack out)

Comment: I don't know anything about the BouncyCastle library. But, it would HAVE to let you encrypt a message using just the public key. Otherwise there would be no purpose to it.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443151/dazed-and-confused-by-java-security-bouncycastle-apis

Comment: Your comments got the cogs turning,

Updating with correct initialisation code for the encryption engine
kicking myself.

Comment: welp, that didn't work. but I'll update when I have something a bit more concrete. The issue lies in the transmission, I'm sure. Checked on the server code (gen a keypair > serialise the public > deserialise public > decrypt with private)