# RSA (client side encryption/ server decryption)

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa

This is a continuation of the project in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445286/creating-an-asymmetriccipherkeypair-with-just-the-public-key), but without the Bouncy Castle.

So I decided to scrap Bouncy Castle (pity, I loved the name)

ANYWAY

I have a server and a client. the client needs to send a serialized object to the server, the server will then process this object.

It does this, however I'd like to add encryption to the process. But without storing a file or anything like that. the process needs to be session based(in a sense)

So, the client will request a key from the server, the server will generate a key pair and send a key to the client.

Client then uses this key to encrypt the object

```
string key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(RequestKey(tcpclnt));
var RsaClient =new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
while (key.Length > 0) {
     RsaClient.FromXmlString(key);
     var transmit = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringtosend);
                  var encrypted = RsaClient.Encrypt(transmit,false);
```

the server then receives these encrypted bytes and tries to decrypt them

```
 raw = Receive(clientSocket);
 byte[] r = TrimBytes(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(raw),256);
 var sdecrypted = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(RsaServer.Decrypt(r, false));
```

But alas, the server can't do this. On Decryption it throws an error

```
Key does not exist.
```

So, my question is, what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

> UPDATE

Altered the code in the server

```
var RSAKeyInfo = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, new CspParameters(1)).ExportParameters(true);
```

New error

```
The parameter is incorrect
```

Comment: Does the server have the same cryptoservice rsaclient key set?

Comment: @BugFinder : I would assume so, it loads the xml that the server provides

                var RsaClient =new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
                while (key.Length > 0) {
                    RsaClient.FromXmlString(key);

Comment: It does sound like its not seeing that key to decrypt it

Comment: @BugFinder : I thought of that, however the key is stored in the RsaServer, correct? and that is used for the remainder of the thread (I am trying to avoid having anything saved to the pc)

Comment: it maybe, but it depends how you're handling it the server and I guess.. as you would have potentially a key per tcpclient surely? and whats in "requestkey"

Comment: Right now yes, a key per client, Request key is simply the client asking the server for a key.

It's all still very rough, but I want to get the basics don before I pretty it up and add everything else.

Comment: Why are you rolling your own (insecure) cryptosystem, rather than using an established mechanism such as SSL?

Comment: @Iridium : This was mainly just to check if I could do it, but as many of the sites have said, Security is difficult, custom Security even more so.

I'm going to be rewriting today to use an established system (RSA encryption on keys) Rijndael on data, unless you would suggest something else? the size of the data is less than 500 bytes.

Comment: Even using a hybrid encryption model as you describe will not be secure - how will you e.g. prevent man-in-the-middle and replay attacks, ensure data authentication and forward secrecy, etc. etc.? You are far better off using SSL/TLS - it'll be easier, quicker and far more secure than anything you can hack together based on the information from a few websites.

Comment: @Iridium please post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst fine as an exercise in the use of cryptography, the use of basic cryptographic algorithms to build your own system for secure communication is a recipe for insecurity. For every weakness you address in your own system, there are likely 10 (or more!) that you won't even have thought of.

My strong suggestion therefore is to use SSL/TLS to secure your communications. This should provide all the security you need whilst also being straightforward to integrate as the .NET Framework's [`SslStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx) has the necessary functionality to operate as either the [server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145061(v=vs.110).aspx) or [client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145065(v=vs.110).aspx) side of the connection.

Doing this will also allow you to optionally use additional security mechanisms in the future, e.g. certificate based client authentication, with minimal additional effort.